# Error: Initial SockJS "Info" request to server failed, url=wss://.../ws org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 null

Tags: java, spring, websocket, sockjs

Here is my implementation of websocket client over wss like below:

```
public class WebSocketUtils {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleFrameHandler.class);

    public static final String TOMCAT_WEBSOCKET_SSL_CONTEXT = "org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_CONTEXT";

    public WebSocketStompClient getSSLClient() throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, CertificateException {
        WebSocketContainer webSocketContainer = new WsWebSocketContainer();

        StandardWebSocketClient standardWebSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient(webSocketContainer);
        String STORETYPE = "JKS";
        String KEYSTORE = "src/test/resources/clientkeystore.jks";
        String STOREPASSWORD = "123456";
        String KEYPASSWORD = "123456";

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(STORETYPE);
        File kf = new File(KEYSTORE);
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(kf), STOREPASSWORD.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(ks, KEYPASSWORD.toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(ks);

        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
        Map<String, Object> sslProperites = new HashMap<>();
        sslProperites.put(TOMCAT_WEBSOCKET_SSL_CONTEXT, sslContext);
        standardWebSocketClient.setUserProperties(sslProperites);

        WebSocketTransport webSocketTransport = new WebSocketTransport(standardWebSocketClient);
        SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(Arrays.asList(webSocketTransport));
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);

        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        return stompClient;
    }
}
```

When trying to connect

```
protected void connectAndSubscribeToWS() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, IOException {
    final String websocketUrl = applicationUrl.replace("http", "ws") + "/ws";
    final String queuePath = "/queue/0";

    webSocketClient = new WebSocketUtils().getSSLClient();
    WebSocketHttpHeaders webSocketHttpHeaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
    ListenableFuture<StompSession> connect = webSocketClient.connect(websocketUrl, new WebSocketHttpHeaders(), new StompHeaders(), new SimpleSessionHandler());

    this.session = connect.get();

    frameHandler = new SimpleFrameHandler();
    this.session.subscribe(queuePath, frameHandler);
}
```

I receive an error:

> ERROR | 2022-05-09 14:54:39 | [main] client.SockJsClient:265 - Initial
> SockJS "Info" request to server failed,
> url=wss://autoorder-is-frex-fxao-q.apps.ocp4q.bbh.com/ws
> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404
> null

Comment: Hi, can you please share the analysis if solved? I am facing same problem.